# Detecting changes to element's attribute(s)

Tags: angular

In Angular, is there any way to detect changes to an element's attribute value?  What I would like to do is monitor any changes to an element's style, more specifically the style display value and then perform some operation when it changes.

A directive's @HostBinding doesn't seem to work as it will *set* the value on the elementRef rather than just query it.  This needs to be a readonly operation.

Comment: can you please post the code?

Comment: There is no code.  I'm just asking is this possible?